# How do you determine what type of canaries are used for stack protection?

Tags: c, gcc, stack, buffer-overflow

I'm reading about Canaries on the buffer overflow protection wiki and don't understand how to tell which canary are used in a program, that being terminator, random and random XOR.

I'm on Debian 32-bit with a program in C with GCC version `10.3.0`.

After compiling with `-fstack-protector` and looking at what I think is the value stored on the stack for the canary, I see that the value changes every time the program is started.

Does this mean that random canaries are used?

Is there a way to know absolutely what type of carny is used?

Is it listed somewhere in GCC docs or can the types be determined looking at the program in GDB?

Comment: Two helpful articles: https://www.sans.org/blog/stack-canaries-gingerly-sidestepping-the-cage/, and https://mcuoneclipse.com/2019/09/28/stack-canaries-with-gcc-checking-for-stack-overflow-at-runtime/.  To answer your question: it sounds like your particular version of GCC is using a random canary (or perhaps a random XOR canary).  Other types might include Null canary, Terminator canary and Custom canary.  You can always generate assembly output ("gcc  -S myfile.c" with "-fstack-protector" or "-fstack-protector-all"), or look at the GCC source code.